# Can the world economic crisis affect Brazil that much as stated by our President?

Tags: economics, brazil

So, as most of you probably know, Brazil is in a [deep economic crisis](http://www.businessinsider.com/brazil-indicators-look-like-2008-2015-8). (I'm a brazilian, but I'm linking a outsource media for reference).

One of the consequences of this crisis, is the Brazilian Reais value. It's falling quite a lot, and fast. This has serious consequences on many of Brazilian industries segments, like software development, oil and minerals exploration, and tourism.

Some of the political parties and big figures here are defending that the value of the Brazilian real is going down because of the economic crisis that's been going on around the world.

But, the main point here is that even the President Dilma Roussef made such statement.
[Here is one of those statements from Presidente Dilma Roussef herself](http://g1.globo.com/politica/noticia/2015/03/dilma-pede-paciencia-e-diz-que-sociedade-precisa-dividir-esforco.html).

I have some knowledge of economics, but nothing on such scale to know if that's true or not.

So, is this kind of statement true?

Here is another example, [an political affiliated site about it states the same.](http://www.brasil247.com/pt/247/economia/194103/Dilma-tinha-raz%C3%A3o-mundo-vive-nova-crise-global.htm)

Note: I do not wish to discuss politics, I just wanted to know if Dilma statement is precise.

To quote:

"a presidente Dilma Rousseff admitiu que o Brasil passa por dificuldades, consequências da crise financeira mundial e da "maior seca da história"

The president Dilma Rousseff admitted that Brazil is undergoing difficulties, consequences of the financial crisis and of the biggest drought in history.

Disclaimer: These links are in portuguese. I translated the above text to the best of my ability, but anyone willing to contribute may edit the question to provide a more clear and concise question.

Comment: As it stands this question is about a broad general statement. If you can narrow it down to a specific notable claim it might work better.

Comment: Would "is the global economy in recession?" be a adequately specific question?

Comment: @Sklivvz , Jon, please, take a look and check if the question is a better fit for this site now.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades, if you could lend a hand as well.. It's important to us to get this information out.

Comment: I don't think that'll work - it's still a subjective question. Does the world economy affect Brazil's? Of course. Is global economic weakness the main driver for Brazil's troubles? A "major" cause? Or are other factors more important? That's subjective, and really needs an economist more than a skeptic to answer.

Comment: An skeptic economist? :)